# Custom streaming implementation

Tags: java, android, stream, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to implement my own version of streaming. I'm sending byte arrays over a websocket. Once I get the first message I write it to a temporary and using android's `MediaPlayer` to play the file. For the first message everything works fine, I turn the byte array into an mp3 and audio comes out. However I'm not really sure how to keep writing to the file every time a message comes over.

some example code

```
File test;
FileOutputStream fos;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
FileInputStream MyFile;
```

Everytime a message comes through this code gets run.

```
                try {
                    if (fos == null) {
                        test = File.createTempFile("TCL", "mp3", getCacheDir());
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(test);
                        fos.write(bytearray);

                        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        MyFile = new FileInputStream(test);
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MyFile.getFD());
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                        if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }

                    }else{
                        fos.write(bytearray);

                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I thought I could just keep writing incoming byte[]'s to the file but that doesn't seem to be working. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do (play the audio in a file that keeps growing indefinitely) is not supported by MediaPlayer.  Instead, look into decoding the audio yourself and sending the raw PCM data to [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html).  It's a lot more work, but AudioTrack is the easiest way to progressively play a stream of audio data.

Comment: I'm giving this a try, I already tried on implementation and it didn't work for me, it played the first byte[] and I heard the audio, then it stopped, any links to examples I could take a look at?

Comment: I can't recommend a specific example as all the code I've written to do AudioTrack streaming is closed source.  But you do have to put the AudioTrack in stream mode, and you have to keep writing to it.  I'm sure there's enough keywords here to do a search for some samples.  :-)

Comment: Thanks, I have it kind of working, it's reading all the byte[]s but is only coming back as static. I'll figure it out, Thanks!

Comment: Also bear in mind that you have to decode the audio if it's encoded.  For example, AudioTrack won't accept mp3 encoded data, so you have to convert it to raw PCM data before writing it.  This is a whole separate problem to solve.